# How to delete a newline (\n) if it is not followed by double quotes

Tags: bash, shell

I have two lines:

```
abc,efg,"hij
kl","dfds,f"
```

I want to delete the newline character at the end of the first line, but only if it is not followed by `"`. That is, I want this result:

```
echo 'abc,efg,"hij
kl","dfds,f"' | xxxxxxxxxx   - >  abc,efg,"hijkl","dfds,f"
```

but

```
abc,efg,"hij"
"kl","dfds,f"
```

should remain as 2 lines itself

Comment: Have you tried any RegEx?

Comment: I don't really understand the context. Are you saying you have a two-line file, and you want to edit that file?

Comment: Also, "shell" is really vague. What shell are you using? The Windows Command Prompt? Bash?

Comment: Sorry for being vague. it is in bash. requirement is to load the file to database.
something like 
echo 'abc,efg,"hij <\n> 
kl","dfds,f"' |  xxxxxxxxxx should give abc,efg,"hijkl","dfds,f"
assume that to be a file with random occurances of such instances.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this awk one-liner may help you:

```
awk '/[^"]$/{printf "%s",$0;next}7'
```

testing with your data:

```
kent$  echo 'abc,efg,"hij
kl","dfds,f"'|awk '/[^"]$/{printf "%s",$0;next}7'                         
abc,efg,"hijkl","dfds,f"
```

this one-liner works if you have multiple (>2) continuous lines not ending with `"`, for example:

```
kent$  echo 'abc,efg,"hij
abc,efg,"hij
abc,efg,"hij
abc,efg,"hij
kl","dfds,f"'|awk '/[^"]$/{printf "%s",$0;next}7'
abc,efg,"hijabc,efg,"hijabc,efg,"hijabc,efg,"hijkl","dfds,f"
```

Answer (score 0):

Manipulation of `ORS` let you do that.

```
cat file
abc,efg,"hij
kl","dfds,f"
"this should be on its own line","but 
this shouldn't"

awk '/[^"]$/{ORS=""} !/[^"]$/{ORS="\n"} 1' file
abc,efg,"hijkl","dfds,f"
"this should be on its own line","but this shouldn't"
```

Comment: Or even shorter: `awk '{/[^"]$/?ORS="":ORS="\n"} 1' file`

Comment: Thanks for the solution. It worked.  
i am a bit new to awk, so i have 2 questions,  
1.in awk / / is that used as if condition?  
2.what is the use of 1 used at the end?

Comment: `//` is used for regex delimiters.